# How to programmatically deploy a Google Apps Script as a standard GCP project

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-api

Using the Node.js client for Google Apps Script API, I am able to deploy a script.  However, according to Google's documentation and my own trial-and-error with the [run method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#node.js), in order to trigger that script to run from the Node.js client, the script must be a **standard** Google Cloud Platform (GCP) script, not a **default** GCP script (see their [documentation on the difference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects)).  By default, all Apps Scripts are [unsurprisingly] **default** GCP projects.

In order to change a **default** Apps Script to become a **standard** Apps Script, it seems that I would have to manually visit in a browser the settings for that default script project in the [Apps Script dashboard](https://script.google.com) and manually place it into a standard GCP project.

However, my aim is to automate the process of deploying and executing these scripts via the API. So this manual settings change in a web browser defeats the entire purpose.  I cannot find any documentation on how to do this programmatically.  Any leads much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, what you want cannot be achieved as in order to change the attached GCP project of an Apps Script project should be done manually.

You can check a list of methods supported by the Apps Script API [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  It seems like an oversight that the API supports direct interaction with sheets, docs, gmail, calendar, etc.  But nothing for forms.